# How do I simulate a scrollbar click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I simulate a scrollbar click with jQuery?  So, if a user clicks on a div that says "scroll down," it'll be the exact same behavior as if he/she clicked on the down arrow of the browser's scrollbar.  Using the current browser's behavior would be optimal, vs. doing something like `$.browser.scrolldown(200,'fast')`.

Something like `$.browser.triggerDownArrowOnScrollBar()` would be sweet!

Comment: Just to ask the obvious (if irrelevant) question... why would you want to do this??

Comment: I want to do this because I'm trying to convince my team at work to have our website auto-focus on the search bar when the page loads, since our website, http://www.biblestudytools.com, is centered around the search feature.  One argument is that, if we auto-focus, it disables the up/down arrow keys on the keyboard, since the cursor is blinking in the search box.

Comment: Solution could be to add listeners on the search box for up/down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to scroll to different points on the page? This can be done like this:

```
$.scrollTo('#your-div');
```

Using: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

-

If you want to find when the user scrolls, you can use:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // your actions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you just want to scroll the page up/down by a fixed amount:

```
/* Scroll down 10px */
$.scrollTo($(window).scrollTop()-10);

/* Scroll up 10px */
$.scrollTo($(window).scrollTop()+10);
```

Comment: This is helpful!  I'm actually looking to avoid fixed amounts, but use whatever the browser uses for scrolling up and down.  Firefox might do 10 px, but Safari might do 15px...